# Convert string to TCHAR* in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

How to convert string to TCHAR* in VC++ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved it using `(TCHAR*)str.c_str()`

Comment: This answer is not safe as `c_str()` returns a `const char*` and you're removing the constness without a const cast or a buffer (the safest way). If the contents of the string are modified it will corrupt the state of the system.

Comment: No, just no. Now you can't switch your project to UNICODE mode.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is Unicode, you need `MultiByteToWideChar`. Otherwise, just use `str.c_str();`

Comment: My project is not Unicode but when i am using str.c_str(), it gives error as cannot conver const char* to TChar*

Comment: you probably want to cast to `(const TCHAR*)str.c_str()`, so it doesn't complain about the const conflict.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <atlstr.h>

String dir="hello world";
char * data = new char[dir.size() + 1];
copy(dir.begin(), dir.end(), data);
data[dir.size()] = '\0'; 
USES_CONVERSION;
TCHAR* directory = A2T(data);
```