# Converting string to tchar in VC++

Tags: string, visual-c++, tchar

how I can convert string to tchar in VC++?

`string internetprotocol="127.4.5.6";`

```
 TCHAR szProxyAddr[16];
```

i want to set:

`szProxyAddr=internetprotocol;`

how i can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to TCHAR\* in VC++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192388/convert-string-to-tchar-in-vc)

Comment: i have compiler error  C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'TCHAR *' to 'TCHAR [16]'

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <atlstr.h>


string internetprotocol="127.4.5.6";
TCHAR szProxyAddr[16]; 

_tcscpy_s(szProxyAddr, CA2T(internetprotocol.c_str()));
```

`_tcscpy_s` is generic `strcpy` version which works both in Unicode and Multi-Character configurations. `CA2T` converts `const char*` to `TCHAR*`, according to `szProxyAddr` variable type.

Be careful with destination variable length.

Comment: This gives me `Error: no instance of overloaded function "wcscpy_s" matches the argument list`

Comment: that's perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
#include <atlstr.h>
_tcscpy_s(szProxyAddr, CA2T(internetprotocol.c_str()));
```