# LPCTSTR typecast for use with GetFileAttributes

Tags: c++, winapi, casting

I´m trying to build a method to see if a file exists.
the method in it´s current isn´t complete form.
i´m trying to figur out whyy it doesn´t behave as code.

```
    BOOL FileExists(LPCTSTR szPath)
        {
            //MessageBox(NULL,szPath,L"File Error",MB_OK);
          DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

            switch(dwAttrib)
            {

                case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY:
                    MessageBox(NULL,L"FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY",L"File Error",MB_OK);
                    break;
                case FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE:
                    MessageBox(NULL,L"FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE",L"File Error",MB_OK);
                    break;
                case FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME:
                    MessageBox(NULL,L"FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME",L"File Error",MB_OK);
                    break;
                case FILE_INVALID_FILE_ID:
                    MessageBox(NULL,L"FILE_INVALID_FILE_ID",L"File Error",MB_OK);
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)dwAttrib,L"File Error",MB_OK);
                    break;
            }
return true;
        }
```

this is how i call the method:

```
FileExists((LPCWSTR)path.c_str());
```

this is where my file resides:

```
std::string path = "C:\\smiley.bmp"
```

i always end up here, no mather in what order the switched is coded:

```
FILE_INVALID_FILE_ID
```

i'm wondering if i'm typecastings correct to `"LPCTSTR"`.

Because i tried using a MessageBox to display the contents of `"szPath"` and it showed up as human unreadeble format.

the path i provide is correct, properly escaped.
how can i check if `"szPath"` contains the proper information?

Comment: `MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)dwAttrib,L"File Error",MB_OK);` What the?!?! What on earth are you doing? This is a recipe for disaster. Please remove it.

Comment: wel, it´s commented out ... but i do tend to use a messagebox to figure out what is happening!

Comment: Casting a `DWORD` to a `LPCWSTR` and printing it out won't help you figure anything out. Best case scenario: it will print out garbage.

Comment: You have to understand what these casts do. They do not do what you think they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is based on `char`, so when you call `.c_str()`, you can a `char *`.

But `LPCWSTR` is a pointer to  a *wide character* string.

I believe, if you're compiling with `UNICODE` enabled (so `LPCTSTR` == `LPCWSTR`), you'll need to use `std::wstring`.

Relevant:

- [Converting string to tchar in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454793/converting-string-to-tchar-in-vc)

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but i´m a bit lost now!

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring

what do i need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Casting does not convert a string into a wide string. It just tells the compiler to shut up, and the error will move. You need the L prefix on literal strings to make them wide strings. And you need to use wstring instead of string.

```
std::wstring path = L"C:\\smiley.bmp";
FileExists(path.c_str());
```

Comment: Ok, i did it wrong and forgot to add the 'L' in the path variable.
the software compiles fine, but still i hit the same point 'FILE_INVALID_FILE_ID'.
i added #include <windows.h>, it should work, because the file is on that spot