# Reading text from txt file and putting it in static text field, mfc

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I read one line of text from external .txt file, and when I try to put it in static text field of a dialog via `SetWindowText` with:

```
string line;

ifstream highscore ("highscore.txt");
if (highscore.is_open())
{
    getline(highscore, line);
}

staticText.SetWindowText(_T(line));
```

I get the following error:

> Error: identifier "Lline" is undefined.

Is there any way to read string from .txt file and putting it to static text field?

Comment: The `T` macros is for string och characters literals, e.g. `T("Foo")`.

Comment: and wifstream (the stinkier version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is the macro `_T` is defined like:

```
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#define _T(x) L ##x
#else
#define _T(x) x
#endif
```

So since `_UNICODE` is defined

```
staticText.SetWindowText(_T(line));
```

Is being converted to

```
staticText.SetWindowText(Lline);
```

Which is giving you the undeclared identifier.

You can either convert the the `std::string` into a `TCHAR*` using one of the answer on [Converting string to tchar in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454793/converting-string-to-tchar-in-vc) or you could use a `std::wstring` to store the line and a `std::wifstream` to read from the file.  If you do this then:

```
staticText.SetWindowText(_T(line));
```

Would become

```
staticText.SetWindowText(line.c_str());
```