# convert std::string to const tchar*

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I have a function that takes in a parameter called arrayOfStrings defined as below:

```
const TCHAR* arrayOfStrings[] = { L"Test" };
```

Now I would like to convert strings to the type above, but I don't know how. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454793/converting-string-to-tchar-in-vc) provides a solution for converting string to tchar, but not const tchar*. [This other link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12245/) shows how to convert string to tchar*, but not const tchar*, and the memory allocation is a problem for me with this second solution. As you can probably tell, I am very new to c++, so any educational tips would be appreciated as well.

Comment: It's likely `TCHAR` not `tchar`. Since you initialize it with a wide-character arrays (the `L` prefix), you can only use a `std::wstring` because `TCHAR` is probably a typedef for `wchar_t`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it is TCHAR. Edited.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a std::wstring to const TCHAR*?

Comment: Yes, calling `wstring.c_str()` will return `const wchar_t*`. Though in MSVC you can switch between UNICODE and ANSI, that will affect the type of TCHAR.

Comment: @NavidNazari If `TCHAR` is really a typedef for `wchar_t`, you can simply use `mywstring.c_str()` to get the underlying `const wchar_t*` array. The same thing can be done to convert `std::string` to `const char *`, but you have to know which type is `TCHAR` (`char` or `wchar_t`).

Comment: What you have there is not C++ per se. It's WinAPI which is a library written in C. Hence the whole shebang when it comes to character arrays.

Comment: @Ron Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @rustyx neither std::string.c_str() nor std::wstring.c_str() are sutable conversions with my current settings. Would switching between ANSI and UNICODE help?

Comment: A *strong* recommendation is not to use `TCHAR` in new code, but decide on `wchar_t` and make your projects "Use Unicode character set". The duality of `TCHAR` being switchable between char/wchar_t hasn't been useful since the 1990's.

Comment: @Holt TCHAR is of type wchar_t, but when I use .c_str on my wstring, I get the error: "cannot convert from const wchar_t* to const TCHAR**"

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. That is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach, which will work with all C++ standards, would be

```
 #include <string>

 #include <windows.h>    //   or whatever header you're using that specifies TCHAR

 int main()
 {
       std::string test("Hello");     //   string to be converted

       //   first, if you need a const TCHAR *

       std::basic_string<TCHAR> converted(test.begin(), test.end());

       const TCHAR *tchar = converted.c_str();

       //   use tchar as it is in the required form (const)

       //   second, if you need a TCHAR * (not const)

       std::vector<TCHAR> converted2(test.begin(), test.end());

       TCHAR *tchar2 = &converted2[0];

       // use tchar2 as it is of the required form (non-const).

 }
```

`std::basic_string` does not provide a means in all C++ standards to obtain a non-`const` pointer to its data, but `std::vector` does.    (Assuming you don't use an explicit conversion to introduce or remove `const`ness).

In C++17 and later, things are simpler:   the `basic_string::data()` has both a `const` and non-`const` overload, which wasn't the case before the 2017 standard.    Before C++11, the data in a `basic_string` was not guaranteed to be contiguous by the standard (even if implementations typically implemented things that way) but `c_str()` did provide the address of the first character of a contiguous array. The net effect is that, in C++17 and later, appropriate overloads of `basic_string::data()` or `basic_string::c_str()` can be used, without a need for cast to change `const`ness, and without resorting to a `vector` (which has been guaranteed to have contiguous elements in all C++ standards).

Points to note in both cases

1. The pointers (`tchar` and `tchar2`) are invalidated if their respective containers (`converted` or `converted2`) are resized or if they cease to exist.  For example, don't use the data pointed to by `tchar` if `converted` has passed out of scope, since data `tchar` points at will no longer exist.
2. It is simply undefined behaviour to use the pointers to run past the end (no magical resizing when using the pointers).

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer!

Comment: RE _"`std::basic_string` does not provide a means to obtain a non-`const` pointer to its data"_ : This is not correct: you can use the [non-`const` overload of the `std::basic_string::data()` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to modify the internal string content.

Comment: Continuing my comment above - In addition, even before the introduction of the non-`const` `data()` method overload in C++17, it was possible to write _in-place_ `std::basic_string`s using `&s[0]`.

Comment: @Mr.C64 - yeah, okay.  Things changed in C++17.   Before C++11 there also wasn't a guarantee that data in a `basic_string` be contiguous, or that  `data()` and `c_str()` give the same pointers either.   I'll update shortly to reflect